# Gettig error: object of type...has no len()

Tags: python

I'm trying to get PMI count from work part file which is opened in NX software in Python, but getting error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NXOpen.Annotations.PmiCollection' has no len()
```

[image]
Code:

```
lw = theSession.ListingWindow
lw.Open()
theSession  = NXOpen.Session.GetSession()
theParts = theSession.Parts
theWorkPart = theParts.Work
allPMIObjects = theWorkPart.PmiManager.Pmis
count1 = len(allPMIObjects)
lw.WriteLine(count1)
lw.Close()
```

Documentation link: https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/data_services/resources/nx/11/nx_api/custom/en_US/nxopen_python_ref/NXOpen.Annotations.PmiCollection.html

Equivalent vb code: http://nxjournaling.com/content/find-out-if-part-has-any-pmi

Comment: That just means that that class doesn't implement length. Nowhere in the documentation is it clear how you'd get a PMI count from it.

Comment: In a python shell, try doing a `dir()` on that object and see if any of the methods or attributes look like they would offer a size or length.

Comment: Since python is in-built in NX software, I won't able to do that.

Comment: Note that in the code equivalent/sample you provided, the collection object was cast to an array before length was checked: `allpmi.ToArray.Length`

Comment: @Experimenter: surely you can run a `print(dir(allPMIObjects))` or similar expression?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: tried but unable to see output, same above error.

Comment: @Experimenter: the error you got from the `len()` call. You'd have to *not execute that call*, `dir()` doesn't use `len()` on an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that gives count of PMIs from active part and assert if count is changed (here 3):

```
lw = theSession.ListingWindow
lw.Open()
# Custom code starts to get PMI count in part and check
theSession  = NXOpen.Session.GetSession()
theParts = theSession.Parts
theWorkPart = theParts.Work
allPMIObjects = theWorkPart.PmiManager.Pmis
i = 0
for p in allPMIObjects:
    i = i + 1
lw.WriteLine(str(i))
lw.Close()

#if PMI count is changed from 3, raise AssertionError:
assert i == 3
```